# How to cleanly dismount an ext3 partition with a small usb distro or other solution

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-drive

I have a disk that was inside a Nas, that seemed to run to hot and eventually just stopped working(the disk is fine, the nas broke)

I don't have a physical machine with linux on at the moment, so I'm working with it inside an xp machine.

I'm using explore 2fs at the moment, which is fine, but a bit slow for working with the data. I want to use fs-driver to mount it properly in windows, but I think the disk was badly shut down, so there is still some records in the journal.

The fs-driver site says

The Ext2 file system driver of the Ext2 IFS software will refuse mounting an Ext3 file system which contains data in its journal, just like older Linux kernels which have no Ext3 support. In this way data loss and damaging the file system is avoided when the journal is subsequently replayed. So you can access only those Ext3 volumes with the Ext2 IFS software which have been cleanly dismounted beforehand.

SO, I'm looking for a lightweight usb bootable linux distro, that I can dismount the drive cleanly.

Or if anyone has any other solutions, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many to choose from !

My current favorite is SystemRecsueCD http://www.sysresccd.org/

If you want to try several have a look at  http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-multiboot-usb/

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. I'm on a fairly crap connection at the mo, so 260MB was manageable. For reference I booted into the gui, directly from the loader menu, and the viewed file systems via the right click menu. I then use the mount and unmount commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try GParted Live on USB from [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Fedora Live CD on a USB stick](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo). It's not very small (it has 700MB), but it's easy to use and since it's a bit bleeding edge you shouldn't have any issues with new hardware or filesystems (although ext3 is already a bit old).